# Share session among asp.net balanced applications without saving session in DB

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to share session among asp.net balanced applicatiosn without saving session in DB (i.e. without using SQLServer sessionState)?  Actually, could load balancers take care of that by themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share a user session, yes.  You have two options:

1. User an ASP.NET [state server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307598) and have the web servers point to that.
2. Enable [sticky sessions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29) on the load balancer, so that once a session is started on a particular machine, all further requests for that session will go to the same machine.  (really this is the less ideal of the two as it can still have problems if the app pool resets etc.)

There are other applications from MS etc, that you can use to store state also.

Comment: The latter of course is subject to worker process terminations and session state loss unless the former (or a session DB) is utilized anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's not the idea fix, but it would provide a work around for not using any sort of a state server.